# y-value of upper plot frame

Tags: r, plot

How can I determine the y-value of the upper plot frame border in base `R`?

For example, in the plot below the y-value of the upper frame border is not `11.1`, the maximum value of `ylim`.  From trial and error the y-value of the upper frame border appears to be a tiny bit larger than `11.53162` which can be seen if the following line is added to the `R` code below:

```
 lines(T,  rep(11.53162, length(x)), type = 'l', col = 'brown', lwd = 2, lty = 3)
```

How can I obtain that value from `R` without using trial-and-error?

```
T   <- 1:10
x   <- 5 + 0.5 * T
x.u <- 6 + 0.5 * T
x.l <- 4 + 0.5 * T

jpeg('my_plot.jpg')

c(0, (max(x.u)+0.1))
# 0.0 11.1

plot(T, x, xlab = 'x', ylab = 'y', type = 'l', col = 'green', lwd = 2, lty = 1,

     ylim = c(0, (max(x.u)+0.1)), cex.lab = 1.5)
     lines(T,  x.u, type = 'l', col = 'brown', lwd = 2, lty = 3)
     lines(T,  x.l, type = 'l', col = 'brown', lwd = 2, lty = 3)
     lines(T,  rep(11.1, length(x)), type = 'l', col = 'brown', lwd = 2, lty = 3)

dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Use `par("usr")[4]`. `plot(x = 1, y = 1, ylim = c(0, 2))`; `lims <- par("usr")`; `points(x = 1, y = lims[4], col = "red", cex = 2)`

Comment: If I type that line below the plot code it returns the value 11.544 which seems too large for my example.

Comment: "Seems"? I tried `plot(T, x, xlab = 'x', ylab = 'y', type = 'l', col = 'green', lwd = 2, lty = 1, ylim = c(0, (max(x.u)+0.1)), cex.lab = 1.5)`; `lims <- par("usr")`; `points(x = 6, y = lims[4], col = "red", cex = 2, pch = 4)`. I you don't think the point have the desired `y`, you may wish to clarify what you mean by "border". Cheers.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks.  Your second example is pretty convincing.

Comment: When creating two plots I was not able to get the `usr` option to work.  I was able to get Greg Snow's solution to work: `par(mfrow=c(2,1), xpd=NA);plot(x = 1, y = 1, ylim = c(0, 2));top.y <- grconvertY(1, from='npc');points(x = 1, y = top.y, col = "red", cex = 2, pch=4);plot(x = 10, y = 10, ylim = c(0, 20));top.y <- grconvertY(1, from='npc');points(x = 10, y = top.y, col = "red", cex = 2, pch=4);`